# Kotlin class equality fails

Tags: reflection, kotlin

The following snippet shows the result of testing equality of Kotlin `KClass` references obtained from different sources. Their string representations are the same. But their java classes are different. Expected that `c`, `c0` and `c1` are equal. But for some reason they aren't.

Is there some nuance or it's a bug? If it's not a bug what is the reliable way to test equality of `KClass`es?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val c = Int::class
    fun test(v0: Any, v1: Any) {
        val c0 = v0.javaClass.kotlin
        val c1 = v1.javaClass.kotlin
        println("c= $c;  c0= $c0;  c1= $c1") // c= class kotlin.Int;  c0= class kotlin.Int;  c1= class kotlin.Int
        println("c= ${c.java};  c0= ${c0.java};  c1= ${c1.java}") // c= int;  c0= class java.lang.Integer;  c1= class java.lang.Integer
        println("c = c0? ${c == c0};  c0 = c1? ${c1 == c0}") // c = c0? false;  c0 = c1? true
    }
    test(11, 22)
}
```

---

EDIT:

The workaround is to use `KClass.javaObjectType` method.

The docs says:

> Returns a Java Class instance corresponding to the given KClass instance. In case of primitive types it returns corresponding wrapper classes.

I.e. `c.javaObjectType == c1.javaObjectType` is true

But it doesn't justifies why `KClass`es having same string representation are different. At least it's confusing. And it's good idea to note about that in docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case equality fails because `KClass`es are considered equal when they correspond to the same Java's type, not the same Kotlin type. This is false for `int` and `java.lang.Integer`.

The workaround is to use `KClass`'s `javaObjectType` property, which will return Java class (not primitive type) even for Kotlin type compiled into Java's primitive:

```
 fun sameClass(c1: KClass<*>, c2: KClass<*>) = c1.javaObjectType == c2.javaObjectType

 sameClass(Int::class, (1 as Any?)!!.javaClass.kotlin) //true
```

I agree that this semantics is rather confusing, I [filed an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11502) about it.

Also, `KClass` doesn't reflect nullability of Kotlin types, and in case if you need to work with declared Kotlin types precisely, you will need to use `KType`, which does.

---

**UPD:** the issue has been marked as fixed, and the equality is explained in `KClass.equals` KDoc since 1.0.2.

Comment: Is nullability related to class comparison? As i understood classes can not be nullable. Expression types can. But we test equality of classes but not expressions.

Comment: @MarkusMarvell, you are right, it is not. I stated that just as a hint to another thing that `KClass` doesn't have from declared Kotlin types. I'll reformulate the statement to make it more clear.